# Get Meteor to watch node_modules for changes

Tags: meteor

I'm building a Meteor app where a lot of the functionality is residing in external npm packages, that I am building at the same time. I use npm link to keep these in sync with the main repo for now. However, Meteor is not watching the node_modules for changes, and does not automatically reload when I have changed anything in these packages.

Is there a way to configure which paths Meteor should be watching when run in development mode? Or is there a better way of building a Meteor app with lots of packages? I'm new to the Meteor world, but it seems to me that older apps had lot's of packages, but after switching to NPM and ES6, you are just supposed to use module imports. However, I still want this functionality in separate npm packages, since we are building up a flexible ecosystem with plugins etc.

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong but I did the same thing as you before, and my server reloaded every I changed the code of the module

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that this is desirable, due to the sheer number of npm modules (and the many files therein), there will be a performance issue. For me Sublime was using 80-90% of my cpu in watching for changes until I told it not to bother with node_modules.

A change that would be useful (and less costly) would be to get Meteor to do an npm install on first startup. Many times I wait for it to load up, only to find I need an npm install.

Comment: I'm happy to manually specify which files to watch (or it could automatically watch only node modules which are symlinked - those I'm working on), but how can I specify this?